# Find MIN timestamp with multiple categories

Tags: excel

I would like to identify the earliest timestamps per user and date based on the following data table.

[image]

I have found a way to get the earliest time stamp for each user or for each date, but not for each user and date. I am looking to find the earliest timestamp for each dates for both 'Bob' and 'Bill'.

What function can I use to incorporate the multiple users and dates?

Comment: Do you have MINIFS()?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have MINIFS or MAXIFS

Comment: actually you should use a pivot table.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, can you please submit as an answer?

Comment: to properly answer I would need to recreate your data to actually show the settings and final output, and I do not have the time to do that.

Comment: Understood, thanks for the help! For anyone else that stumbles across this thread, build a pivot table and put username and date as row, then time as value with the value field settings set to MIN.

Comment: You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pivot table

[image]

Split like this:

[image]